# Multiplayer Book Copying

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I create a written book, I'm aware that it can be copied.  However, could other players on a multiplayer server copy my book, and, if so, who will be listed as the author?

Answer (score 2):

The author of the book is set when you "sign" it, after that point it cannot be changed and creating a copy will give a book with identical author and contents to the original.

So the only way someone could change the author, would be to re-write the entire thing themselves or edit the files if they're the owner of the server. (This may also be possible with mods, but I don't know of any)